# Why is if statement not working in c++ function?

Tags: c++, if-statement, find, stdvector

In this code I can find an element in vector and can print it's indices too.But if i give an input lets say 1 which is not a vector element,it doesn't print output as "Element Not Found.".The if statement after while loop is not working.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void search(vector<vector<int>> v,int e){
    int i = 0;
    int j = v[0].size() - 1;
    int found = 0;
    while(v[i][j]){
        if(v[i][j] == e){
            found = 1;
            cout<< "Element found at: (" << i <<" , "<< j <<" )"<<endl;                
            break;
        }
        else{
            if(v[i][j] > e){
                j--;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
    if(found == 0){
        cout<< "Element Not Found."<< endl;    
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<vector<int>> v{
        {10,20,30,40},
        {15,25,35,45},
        {27,29,37,48},
        {32,33,39,50}
    };
    int e;
    cout<< "Enter the element to find:";
    cin>> e;
    search(v,e);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my entire code.
Thanks for the tips.

Comment: What is `while(v[i][j]){` supposed to do? Do you know what that does? You alsod don't have any bounds checking anywhere, so you probably get UB at some point when the element is not in the vector.

Comment: @DhanushKumar did you tried the solution below? Do you have any questions or comments on it?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, due to decrementing `j` or incrementing `i` without checking that the result is in bounds - and then accessing the resultant element on the next iteration of the loop.'

Comment: A bit about style: `found` doesn't do much here. The `if` statement can be `if (v[i][j] == e) { std::cout << "Element found\n"; return;`, and then that final `if` can simply be removed; if the loop exits normally the element wasn't found, and the final message can always be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v[i][j]` will continue to iterate until the subscript returns any non-zero value, *(even if it is way out of the valid boundaries)*.

You should introduce this condition into the loop:

```
while(i < v[0].size() && j >= 0) ...;
```

It would be also sane to at least introduce check for `v` being empty. I also want to bring attention to this part:

```
// ...
if(v[i][j] == e) {
    found = 1; // Useless statement 
    cout << "Element found at: (" << i <<" , "<< j <<" )" << endl;                
    break; // We can just place a return here
}
// ...
```

There's no sense in the `found` update, since if the condition is true, yes, we found the sought value, we print and may return (void). So the value of the `found` flag won't be needed for check in the `if` below.

So, in the end, I would suggest you to look toward this solution:

```
void search(vector<vector<int>> v,int e){
    if (!v.size()) {
        std::cout << "Empty." << std::endl;
        return; 
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = v[0].size() - 1;
    int found = 0;
    while(i < v[0].size() && j >= 0){
        if(v[i][j] == e){
            cout<< "Element found at: (" << i <<" , "<< j <<" )"<<endl;                
            return;
        }
        else (v[i][j] > e) ? --j : ++i; // Ternary operator 
    }
    cout << "Element Not Found." << endl;    
}
```

Example:

```
Enter the element to find: 48
Element found at: (2 , 3 )

Enter the element to find: 42
Element Not Found.
```